# Query with join produce uncompleted result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is how relations look like

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :conversation
```

I want to get all Conversations where user is owner or receiver or sender, I am doing it like so

```
[79] pry(main)> Conversation.joins(:messages).where("messages.receiver_id = ? OR messages.sender_id = ? OR conversations.user_id = ?", 2, 2, 2).count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN "messages" ON "messages"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id" WHERE (messages.receiver_id = 2 OR messages.sender_id = 2 OR conversations.user_id = 2)
=> 0
```

But `0` is incorrect, I have Conversation with `user_id: 2`

```
[78] pry(main)> Conversation.where(user_id: 2).count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "conversations" WHERE "conversations"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 2]]
=> 1
```

Any ideas whats wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QueryMethods#joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) performs (read: “is translated to”) a `LEFT INNER JOIN` of tables.

The conversation and messages in the query should be linked themselves via `"messages"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id"`. Yours seem to be not linked.

Now the question is what do you expect to receive as a result. If you want everything, related to the user, despite whether it’s linked internally or not, use [`CROSS JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) (I am not aware of Rails implementation, you might need to execute raw SQL query for that.)

In my opinion, you want to either fix your database, or use [`QueryMethods#left_outer_joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins) to “lazy” join, or just use two single queries.